# Custom Magento 2 container/banner

Tags: xml, magento2

I'm trying to create my own magento 2 theme.
I want to add a header image to all pages on top.

```
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">250</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is my default.xml file.

i thought i could add a reference block inside my default.xml like this:

```
 <referenceContainer name="header.panel"> 
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

But instead of that my banner. How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <referenceContainer name="header.panel"> 
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Note.. This is how you add a block right.

```
<block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
```

Create a block

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="banner" template="banner.phtml"/>
```

and put it inside of

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel"> 
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="banner" template="banner.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

You will have to create within the following folders. 
 app/code/YouTheme/Banners/view/frontend/templates/banner.phtml

Where banner.phtml is where html code will be.

I hope it gave you an idea on how to solve it.